# Nodejs google datastore hangs with no error message

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a weird error using google-cloud/datastore in my nodejs app

```
const googleDatastoreFactory = () => {
  console.log('inside the factory');
  const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
  console.log('imported datastore stuff');
  return new Datastore();
};

export default googleDatastoreFactory;
```

The above factory method hangs at this line

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
```

It literally just sits there (I know this because of my custom logging; console.log). There is no logging or error message from google-cloud/datastore.

Comment: It never times out. It just sits there.

Comment: Can you post your code, that requiring this module? Didn't you forget to call this factory method?